Algorithm for finding enclosing circles for 3 other circles
I have 3 circles which may/may not be touching each other. Is it possible to find algorithmically circle which contains all those circles and have the minimal size?
It seems to be smallest-circle problem but with circles instead of points. I do not think Welzl's algorithm can be used for this case.
I also think that algorithms for computing Circumcircle of triangle can not be used.
Any ideas what could be a good approach?

Check out the problem of Apollonius

Hi Houp, as written this appears to be more of a conceptual/design question rather than a specific programming one. This question could warrant reopening if you can narrow this question down to, for example, a specific language (or at least a finite set of languages) you'll be implementing the algorithm in. Varying languages will have varying capabilities for implementation of given algorithms that may make them not feasible or worthwhile to consider, for example. Otherwise, you might consider asking this question on ComputerScience.SE, instead.

The math should be broadly based on algebraic solution of Apollonius's problem - pick signs corresponding to internal touches, use linear equations with 3 unknowns to create a quadratic equation with 1 unknown (usually radius) which will have up to 2 solutions. You can modify the code from Grand Finale: Circles for n = 3, enclosing circle instead of enclosed i.e. condition sqrt(...)+r_i <= r, and minimum r to get the solution to exactly your problem.

Given n circle centers, compute the convex hull of the circles (which can be done in O(n log n)). Since the convex hull is necessarily a convex polygon, you can apply Welzl’s algorithm to its vertices.

Convex hull of circle is bigger than circle so the result must be bigger than circle.
